# Polyhedron in ExpressionJSON behavior strange

Tags: graphics3d

```
geoInv = ((With[{x662 = #.#}, If[ x662 < 0.00000001, #, #/x662] ]) &);
cubes = Table[Cube[{x, y, z}, 0.8], {x, -3, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, -3, 3}] /. Cube[{(0)..}, _] -> Nothing;
Graphics3D[{Cyan, cubes /. x_Cube -> CanonicalizePolyhedron[x] /. Polyhedron[pts_, g_] :> Polyhedron[geoInv /@ pts, g]}, Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> 0.4]
```

> http://xahlee.info/math/geometric_inversion.html

it produces a graph like this.

[image]

then I add  `// Export["~/tmp.txt", #, "ExpressionJSON"] &` to get the `ExpressionJSON`.

here is part of it

```json
[
                "Polyhedron",
                [
                "List",
                [   "List", -0.14604810996563575,   1.7182130584192445e-2,  -0.14604810996563575],
                [   "List", -0.1406926406926407,    2.1645021645021648e-2,  -0.18398268398268397],
                [   "List", -0.1406926406926407,    -2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.18398268398268397],
                [   "List", -0.14604810996563575,   -1.7182130584192445e-2, -0.14604810996563575],
                [   "List", -0.18398268398268397,   2.1645021645021648e-2,  -0.1406926406926407],
                [   "List", -0.19005847953216373,   2.9239766081871343e-2,  -0.19005847953216373],
                [   "List", -0.19005847953216373,   -2.9239766081871343e-2, -0.19005847953216373],
                [   "List", -0.18398268398268397,   -2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.1406926406926407]
                ],
        [
            "List",
              [ "List", 1,  2,  3,  4],
              [ "List", 5,  6,  2,  1],
              [ "List", 6,  7,  3,  2],
              [ "List", 7,  8,  4,  3],
              [ "List", 8,  5,  1,  4],
              [ "List", 8,  7,  6,  5]
        ]
],
```

but

```
Polyhedron[
    {
                {    -0.14604810996563575, 1.7182130584192445e-2, -0.14604810996563575},
                {  -0.1406926406926407, 2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.18398268398268397},
                {  -0.1406926406926407, -2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.18398268398268397},
                {  -0.14604810996563575, -1.7182130584192445e-2, -0.14604810996563575},
                {  -0.18398268398268397, 2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.1406926406926407},
                {  -0.19005847953216373, 2.9239766081871343e-2, -0.19005847953216373},
                {  -0.19005847953216373, -2.9239766081871343e-2, -0.19005847953216373},
                {  -0.18398268398268397, -2.1645021645021648e-2, -0.1406926406926407}
    },
  {
   
              {  1, 2, 3, 4},
              {  5, 6, 2, 1},
              {  6, 7, 3, 2},
              {  7, 8, 4, 3},
              {  8, 5, 1, 4},
              {  8, 7, 6, 5}
  }
] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

the expressionjson doesn't work.

So how to make it work?

Comment: Look at the representation of numbers. JSON uses scientific "E" notation which is not valid in Mathematica. You shouldn't blindly copy the JSON and paste it into Mathematica, but **Import** it so that the numbers get converted properly: ``Import["~/tmp.txt", "ExpressionJSON"]``

Comment: I will put it as an example to three.js library. It looks really beautiful

Answer (score 2):

e is not a valid form. That's it.

```
Polyhedron[
    {
                {  -0.14604810996563575, 1.7182130584192445*10^-2, -0.14604810996563575},
                {  -0.1406926406926407, 2.1645021645021648*10^-2, -0.18398268398268397},
                {  -0.1406926406926407, -2.1645021645021648*10^-2, -0.18398268398268397},
                {  -0.14604810996563575, -1.7182130584192445*10^-2, -0.14604810996563575},
                {  -0.18398268398268397, 2.1645021645021648*10^-2, -0.1406926406926407},
                {  -0.19005847953216373, 2.9239766081871343*10^-2, -0.19005847953216373},
                {  -0.19005847953216373, -2.9239766081871343*10^-2, -0.19005847953216373},
                {  -0.18398268398268397, -2.1645021645021648*10^-2, -0.1406926406926407}
    },
  {
   
     {  1, 2, 3, 4},
              {  5, 6, 2, 1},
              {  6, 7, 3, 2},
              {  7, 8, 4, 3},
              {  8, 5, 1, 4},
              {  8, 7, 6, 5}
  }
] // Graphics3D
```

[image]